# Web Scraping - Detective Conan

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to download all the episodes of detective Conan from **https://www.kiss-anime.ws/** (kudos to them). While scraping the download URL from the website, I am facing an issue.

Let's say I want to download the first episode of detective Conan, so I use this URL (**https://www.kiss-anime.ws/Anime-detective-conan-1**) to scrape the download URL. Now when I try to get the HTML code of the website, to extract the download URL, using the following code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.kiss-anime.ws/Anime-detective-conan-1', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
```

I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "refine.py", line 41, in
>   
>       webpage = urlopen(req).read()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py",
>   line 222, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py",
>   line 531, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py",
>   line 640, in http_response
>       response = self.parent.error(   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py",
>   line 569, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py",
>   line 502, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py",
>   line 649, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily
>   Unavailable

I don't want to go to every link and click on the download link manually as there are over 900 episodes. Once I have the link I will download the episode using the following code: (in case anyone is wondering how I would do that)

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://www.kiss-anime.ws/download.php?id=VkE3eFcvTlpZb0RvKzJ0Tmx2V2ROa3J4UWJ1U09Ic0VValh1WGNtY2Fvbz0=&key=B2X2kHBdIGdzAxn4kHmhXDq0XNq5XNu1WtujWq==&ts=1584489495")
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you limited to using only built-in Python modules or you can use third party modules, like `requests`, too?

Comment: Daweo when I use the requests module, the site detects that I am using a bot using hidden input hence I am not able to scrape data. Do you have any other solution in mind?

Comment: I suggest taking look at `Selenium`, as by using it you looks like human user for webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently there are 808 episodes. Have a look at this code, there is a lot going on here, but it's simple to understand. I tested the download for around 5-6 episodes and it works...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from http.client import RemoteDisconnected
import time


def get_browser():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    return driver


driver = get_browser()
page_url = "https://www.kiss-anime.ws/Anime-detective-conan-1"

try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
    driver.get(page_url)
except TimeoutException:
    raise Exception(f"\t{page_url} - Timed out receiving message from renderer")
except RemoteDisconnected:
    raise Exception(f"\tError 404: {page_url} not found.")

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "selectEpisode")))
driver.find_element_by_id("selectEpisode").click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

options = soup.find("select", attrs={"id": "selectEpisode"}).find_all("option")
print(f"Found {len(options)} episodes...")


base_url = "https://www.kiss-anime.ws/"
for idx, option in enumerate(options):
    print(f"Downloading {idx+1} of {len(options)}...")
    page_url = option['value']

    try:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
        driver.get(page_url)
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"\t{page_url} - Timed out receiving message from renderer")
        continue
    except RemoteDisconnected:
        print(f"\tError 404: {page_url} not found.")
        continue

    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "divDownload")))
    driver.find_element_by_id("divDownload").click()
    print(f"\t Downloading...")
    time.sleep(15)


driver.quit()
print("done")
```

So, firstly, I'm opening up the URL in a chrome browser, and reading the dropdown values which are 808 in total. Now I am walking through each of those 808 URLs to fetch the actual link we need to download the video. By using the `.click()` in the loop, I'm actually simulating a button click and the video starts to download. Remember to change the `time.sleep(x)` where `x` should represent the approx time(seconds) it takes for you to download one episode according to your internet speed.

You need to install `selenium` and `bs4` packages using `pip install`. Also, download [chromedriver.exe](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and ensure it's in the same path as that of this script.

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful effort, this code really works and I think I will be able to enjoy this anime now. Though there is a slight problem, sometimes when the link is clicked by the program it redirects the bot to a bogus ad website, like the general popups we face while surfing the browser. Is there a way to ensure that when the linked is clicked by the program only the episode is downloaded and nothing else happens. Please help me solve this. :)

Comment: You could probably try installing an ad-blocker extension on the chrome browser, and after you do that, just remove this line `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")` from the code. Also, do consider upvoting the answer if it helped...